# KNN with the R DMwR package

Tags: r, nlp, ml, knn

I am trying run KNN on text. However I keep getting errors stated below. Any ideas?

When I run this code:

```
nn3 <- kNN(Type ~ .,trainQB,testQB,norm=FALSE,k=3)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error in knn(train[, -tgtCol], test[, -tgtCol], train[, tgtCol], ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 6)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In knn(train[, -tgtCol], test[, -tgtCol], train[, tgtCol], ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In knn(train[, -tgtCol], test[, -tgtCol], train[, tgtCol], ...) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

I tried changing my test and train data to vectors:

```
nn3 <- kNN(as.vector(Type) ~ .,as.vector(trainQB$Category),
       as.vector(testQB$Category),norm=FALSE,k=3)
```

and i get this error:

```
Error in train[, -tgtCol] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

This is an example of how my data looks like:

```
**Error      Category         Type**
signup      Account issue     1
login       Account issue     2
```

And here is the rest of my code:

```
View(QBdata)
labels<-QBdata$Type)
View(labels)
idxs <- sample(1:nrow(QBdata),as.integer(0.7*nrow(QBdata)))
trainQB <- QBdata[idxs,]
testQB <- QBdata[-idxs,]
nn3 <- kNN(Type ~ .,trainQB,testQB,norm=FALSE,k=3)
```

According to the DMwR package, the function KNN is written this way:

```
kNN(form, train, test, norm = T, norm.stats = NULL, ...)
```

where form is an object of the class formula describing the functional form of the classification model.

when i run dput( head(trainQB) ) i get:

```
structure(list(Error = structure(c(45L, 23L, 67L, 63L, 12L, 27L
), .Label = c("10k limit switch to online", "access", "accounting ....class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(9L, 
11L, 2L, 7L, 4L, 7L), .Label = c("Access errors", "Account", 
"Bank sync errors", "Convert ", "General Error", "Install errors", 
"plan features", "pricing issues", "setup errors", "signup errors", 
"upgrade errors"), class = "factor"), Type = c(6L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
7L, 9L)), .Names = c("Error", "Category", "Type"), row.names = c(39L, 
34L, 51L, 53L, 41L, 64L), class = "data.frame"
```

Thanks!

Comment: `as.vector` would remove any dimensions from a matrix object.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: I would instead be investigating what it was about my data that was throwing the error. Are you supplying factor variables to arguments that are expecting numeric values? Your "example" is rather imprecise from a coding perspective.

Comment: An example of this being used is on the iris dataset where all the values are numeric except Species which is used as form. Maybe i need to process the text into another form before i can input it into the function but thats the part that im unsure of.

Comment: Generally category variables _will_ be 'factor' or 'character'. What does `lapply( trainQB[!names(trainQB) == "Type"] , class)` return. Better yet post `dput( head(trainQB) )`

Comment: i get `class=dataframe`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40285/discussion-between-jenn-and-dwin)

Comment: any idea on what is wrong?